# How to inspect an apartment before renting?

Tags: maintenance

I've had several major problems with the apartment home I've lived in for the past year.

During the summer time, the air-conditioner didn't work well.  It was eventually fixed, but it took a replacement of the outside unit and new insulation in the attic to bring the daytime temperature of my apartment down to 70 from 85 degrees Farenheight.

After the long, dry summer ended, I almost immediately started having leaks in my roof.  The water drips down into my bedroom every time it rains heavily!  Because of the exceptionally dry weather earlier this year, I didn't know about the problem until more than half-way through the year.

However, I did notice a few small stains in the ceiling, as well as a tiny hole.  I wondered what could make such a small hole; now I know!

What are the most important things to look for in terms of telling if an apartment I'm thinking of renting is going to cause me problems?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a good idea to ask people that already live in the building about problems they had and how well does management handles them.